# Script to look for http:// or https:// in input box on keyup and remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to allow members to enter in a URL but I want to remove any http:// or https:// they enter into the URL and keep the rest.

Here is the code I have that's not working:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const $input = document.querySelector('.inputbox');

  if ($input) {
    $input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
      $input.value = $input.value.replace('http://', '');
      $input.value = $input.value.replace('https://', '');
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.inputbox {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px!important;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 3px!important;
  color: #000!important;
  border-style: solid!important;
  border-radius: 5px!important;
  border-color: #000!important;
  border-width: 1px!important;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="funnel">
  <select class="selectbox" name="preurl">
    <option value="http://">http://</option>
    <option value="https://">https://</option>
  </select><input type="text" name="url" class="inputbox" value="" placeholder="URL:" required><br /> Enter the URL you wish people to goto after filling out your form<br /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success" value="Save Settings" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: why not just change it when they are done?

Comment: The code seems to be working in the snippet.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to make it replace both `http://` and `https://`. Also it should only match at the beginning, you can do that in the regexp as well.

Comment: @Barmar For some reason, this is just not working on my page. It works in the snippet code above running it but it will not work on my page. Does this require a special jquery or something to be linked-to in order to work?

Comment: @RandyThomas you just need to add that code at the bottom before the `</body>` closes, when the DOM is ready and it can actually see/find the elements.

Comment: @Barmar As you can see, it's not working here either: https://jsfiddle.net/cabs154d/ so I don't know why it works here and not anywhere else.

Comment: You can't put multiple event names in the first argument to `addEventListener()`. It's not like jQuery `.on()`.

Comment: If you want to use the same function for multiple events, put it in a named function. Then add it as an event listener for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the point.

> In vanilla JavaScript, each event type requires its own event listener. Unfortunately, you can’t pass in multiple events to a single listener like you might in jQuery and other frameworks.

So, for the problem you can solve it like this:

```js
// Setup function
const removeHttp = function (event) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace('http://', '');
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace('https://', '');
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const input = document.querySelector('.inputbox');
  if (input) {
    // Add listeners
    input.addEventListener('change', removeHttp, false);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', removeHttp, false);
    input.addEventListener('paste', removeHttp, false);
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="url" class="inputbox" value="" placeholder="URL:" required><br />
</form>
```